# UnBind Particular Service that is binded with Same Service Connection instance (connection)

Tags: java, android, service, bindservice

Is there Any possiblity to unbind the particular BoundedService from ServiceConnection with same instance for both..Any Help would be appreciated.

```
  public static ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        
        if (className.getClassName().contains("LoggingService")) {
            LoggingService.LogBinder binder = (LoggingService.LogBinder) service;
            myLogService = binder.getService();
            myLogService.LoggingMethod("serviceconnection");
            isBoundLog = true;
        }

        if (className.getClassName().contains("DownloadService")) {
            DownloadService.DownloadBinder binder = (DownloadService.DownloadBinder) service;
            myDwnloadServ = binder.getService();
            isBoundDownload = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        if (className.getClassName().contains("LoggingService")) {
            isBoundLog = false;
        }
        if (className.getClassName().contains("DownloadService")) {
            isBoundDownload = false;
        }
      
    }
};
```